# String to hex TypedArray.map different from Array.from(TypedArray)

Tags: javascript, hex, buffer, typedarray

String to hex is the goal. Getting a different result when using map directly on a TypedArray vs using Array.from on the TypedArray then using map. Can someone help me understand what is going on?

```
var buf = new TextEncoder().encode('hello');

var ret = '';
for (var b of buf) ret += b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').slice(-2);

console.log(
    '\n',
    buf.join(), // 104,101,108,108,111
    '\n',
    buf.map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').slice(-2)).join(''), // 6865000 
    '\n',
    Array.from(buf).join(), // 104,101,108,108,111 
    '\n',
    Array.from(buf).map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').slice(-2)).join(''), // 68656c6c6f 
    '\n',
    ret, // 68656c6c6f 
    '\n',
    decodeURIComponent('%' + ret.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('%')) // hello
);
/*
 104,101,108,108,111 
 6865000 
 104,101,108,108,111 
 68656c6c6f 
 68656c6c6f 
 hello
*/
```

Comment: an `Uint8Array` can't store strings (at least not directly, without encoding them). `.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').slice(-2)` is a string. In typical javascribbidies fashion, it will attempt to convert to number, get `NaN`, convert that to `0` for the typed array, and never throw.

Comment: Are you saying that `Array.prototype.map` returns the type of Array it was called on and not an actual Array?

Comment: `buf.map` is not `Array.prototype.map`. `buf` is not an array, but a typedArray, an `Uint8Array`. See [TypedArray.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map). As an interesting note, yes, you could do `Array.prototype.map.call(buf, x => x.toString(16).padStart(2, '0').slice(-2)).join('')`, which would then also give you `"68656c6c6f"`.

Comment: Interesting I made the assumption that `TypedArray` extended `Array` and would return an `Array` but I see that  `TypedArray` extends the `Object` and therefore returns a `TypedArray`.

Comment: As additional info for the "javascribbidies" from above, here is [the conversion taking place](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-touint8). E.g. `Number('6c')` (no `0x` prefix) will give `NaN` (in a way same as "ToNumber(argument)" in the spec), and then "If number is NaN, +0, -0, +∞, or -∞, return +0". That's where finally the zeroes come from.